# How to pass an argument (args) to a `request.get`?

Tags: swift, api, query-string, urlrequest

I'm trying to find out how to pass an argument (args) to a `request.get`. I know how to pass a token to the HTTP header like this:

```
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
```

But if I was going to pass the email as args to the request, how do I do that?

> GET https://myapi/check_email?email=user1@gmail.com

Comment: can you give some more context to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually belongs to the `URL` and it has nothing to do with the HTTP method. So you need to add a query item to the url:

```
let theURL = URL(string: "https://myapi/check_email")!
var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: theURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)!
let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "email", value: "user1@gmail.com")
urlComponents.queryItems = [queryItem]
let newURL = urlComponents.url!
```

This works on **any** HTTP method (including `GET` `POST`, `PUT`, etc.).